# Как запустить autoplay swiper slider только на разрешении 640?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, swiper

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var swiper = new Swiper(".swiper-slider-main", {
    lazy: true,
    loop: true,
    pagination: {
      el: ".swiper-pagination",
      //type: 'progressbar',
    },
    navigation: {
      nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
      prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
    },
    breakpoints: {
      640: {
        autoplay: {
          delay: 3000,
        },
      },
    },
  });
});
```

Этот код почему-то не работает. Хотя когда запускаю autoplay на всех разрешениях, autoplay работает без проблем. В чем можно быть проблема? И вообще модет ли swiper запускать autoplay только при определенном разрешении? Благодарю за советы)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Внутри `breakpoints` работают только [следующие параметры](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#param-breakpoints): `slidesPerView, slidesPerGroup, spaceBetween, grid.rows`. Автоплей там не работает.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию)